# How to start Itertools cycle from a particular point in Python?

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools

I have created an `itertools` cycle for the English alphabet using the code below,

```
lowercase_letters_cycle = itertools.cycle(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

If I run a `for` loop on this iterator object, the first iteration would give me "a" as the output because the cycle starts from "a". How can I make it so that cycle starts from any letter of my choice?

One way that works is,

```
def start_cycle(letter):
  lowercase_letters_cycle = itertools.cycle(lowercase_letters)
  letter_index = lowercase_letters.index(letter)
  index = 0

  while True:
    if index == letter_index:
      break

    letter = next(lowercase_letters_cycle)
    index += 1

  return lowercase_letters_cycle
```

But is there any shorter method?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that! I made that list because it's useful in the bigger problem of whom this question is a part of, I'll edit that out. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `islice` and `cycle` from the `itertools` module as follows:

```
import string 
import itertools

my_it = itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(string.ascii_lowercase), 3, None)
```

It will yield `d` (the character that comes after the first 3), then `e`, ...., then `z`, then `a`, then `b`, and so on. You can change the number in the second argument to `islice` to start from a different letter.

Comment: Thanks man! Your answer was the one line answer I was looking for. Very appreciated!

Comment: Pleasure! Happy we can help!

Answer (score 2):

The `itertools` documentation supplies a [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for consuming a number of items from an iterator.

```
from itertools import islice
import collections


def consume(iterator, n=None):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is None, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

So you create the cycle, then just consume a bit of it before proceeding.

```
lowercase_letters_cycle = itertools.cycle(string.ascii_lowercase)

consume(lowercase_letters_cycle, ord('n') - ord('a'))

assert next(lowercase_letters_cycle) == 'n')
```

The same `consume` is also available from the [third-party `more-itertools` package](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/).

Comment: (Sorry @PranavHosangadi, I restored your edit that I accidentally erased :) )

Answer (score 1):

You could just slice the input list to start at the index of your choice.

```
offset = 10
lowercase_letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

#                 offset_index to end       + start to offset_index-1
offset_letters = lowercase_letters[offset:] + lowercase_letters[:offset]
offset_letters_cycle = itertools.cycle(offset_letters)
```

Then,

```
for i in range(10):
    print(next(offset_letters_cycle), end=" ")
```

prints:

```
k l m n o p q r s t
```

Comment: Thanks man! I thought of this method but thought that there might be some in-built method to do the same. Is there any?

Comment: @IshanShishodiya You could also consume/throw away the first few items of your iterator with `itertools.islice`.

Comment: @Ishan Other than discarding the first few elements (like you do or with `itertools.islice`) I can't think of any off the top of my head. Since list slicing is included in vanilla python, I'd probably just do it this way unless the list was _huge_ (in which case I'd prefer `islice`)

Comment: Gotcha! Cause the list I am working with is a small one, I can just slice it up and rearrange it. Thanks for your help man! Means a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import string
from itertools import cycle, dropwhile

def start_cycle(letter):
    return dropwhile(lambda x: x!= letter, cycle(string.ascii_lowercase))
```

[`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) will feed the iterable results to its sentinel function - in this case `lambda x: x != letter`, and will "swallow" the results until the function returns `False` for the first time. At that point
the function is no longer called, and the iterable proceeds, yielding any
further values.

Also, note there is no need to convert `ascii_lowercase` to a list,
as strings are already iterables.

Keep in mind that this will run into an infinite loop with 100% CPU if a character not in ascii_lowercase is passed. It is better to guard it with a check:

```
def start_cycle(letter):
    if letter not in string.ascii_lowercase:
         raise ValueError()
    return dropwhile(lambda x: x!= letter, cycle(string.ascii_lowercase))
```